# How do I properly hold a rangefinder-style camera in portrait orientation?

Tags: body, viewfinder, hand-held

The Fujifilm X-Pro1 has a fancy hybrid viewfinder, which can almost magically be switched between EVF and optical modes. In EVF mode, the display is created by reading the main sensor, so it's an exact through-the-lens view. In optical mode, though, you're looking through a dedicated finder window located in the camera's top left corner (from the photographer's point of view).

The optical viewfinder has its pluses and minuses, and the X-Pro1 has some nifty features related to augmenting and mitigating those. But that's not my concern here. The problem is: When I turn the camera 90° to take a photograph in portrait orientation, my right hand hooks over the top of the camera, resting on the shutter button (which is fine), but my left hand stays supporting the lens — and now it's blocking the finder window.

I can move my hand out of the way and hold the square edge of the camera itself, but that's inconvenient, as aperture is adjusted by turning the traditional-style ring on the lens itself. I can squoosh it off to the side, but that's very awkward and not steady. Or I can flip the camera the other way, but then my right hand on the shutter button is supporting the weight of the camera, and that's not really workable.

I'm scratching my head here — this style of camera has been popular for years, even if the Fujifilm line is new. Is there a trick or something I'm missing? At least now I have the option of activating the EVF, but I don't necessarily always want to do that in portrait mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leica manuals have some instructions on this, but it basically boils down to ***not*** holding on to the lens, pretty much as you initially described. In portrait mode, rotate the camera so that the shutter release is at the top and your right hand index finger is on it. Hold the other side of the camera at the bottom corner with your left hand. If you need to adjust the aperture, do that, then move your hand back to the corner.

It's been a long time since I've used one, but I have always found rangefinder just a little awkward for portrait mode shooting. SLRs definitely have an advantage there.